# Trying to get Bootstrap layout working correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the column on the right marked in red (see attached image) to be cable of expanding further down the page without affecting the layout of the row at the bottom other stories. I'm using bootstrap and every time I put more text into this the entire grid moves down. Should I be using span instead of columns?

[image: Layout in red]

Heres the code I got so far.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="span1">
        <h6 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>Here's Why 9/11 Conspiracy</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <h9 class="span10">Newspaper</h9>
      </div>

      <div class="span1">
        <h6 class="text-center">Here's Why 9/11 Conspiracy</h6>
      </div>

    </div>

    <hr style="height:0.3em;" color= '#000000' />
    <hr>
    <div class="row">

     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->

     <div class="span4">


      <h4 class="text-center">Here's Why 9/11 Conspiracy Theories Still Thrive In America</h4>
      <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Mr.Man</i></h5>
      <hr>

      <p style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><span class="firstcharacter">D</span>ublin, It was a sunny and clear Tuesday morning in Knoxville, Tennessee. Sitting in the kitchen of my girlfriend's apartment, I was eating a bowl of cereal -- Honey Nut Cheerios, I still remember -- and browsing the web before making the 15-minute drive to campus for class.

      </p>

      </div>

      <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->

      <div class="span6">
        <h1 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>Terrorists are plotting to blow up five planes</h1>

        <p><b>The threat has been taken so seriously it came close to leading to an outright ban on all hand luggage, a senior insider has revealed.

          </b></p>

        </div>

        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->

        <div class="span2">
          <h4 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>Trending Stories</h4>
          <hr>
          <h5 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <story>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit <b> amet risus.</b></story>

          <h5  style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <story>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.  <b> amet risus.</b></story>

          <h5  style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <story>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.<b> amet risus.</b></story>

        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->

      <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
      <div class="row">
      <hr class="span10" style="height:0.3em;" color= '#3090C7' />
      </div>

      <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
      <div class="row" class="span10">

        <div class="span2">
          <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non  </p> 
        </div>

        <div class="span2">
          <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="span2">
          <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="span2">
          <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="span2">
          <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non  </p> 
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap version 2.x?

Comment: No I'm using version 3? But I'm using span instead of columns

Comment: Try using `col`.  Also maybe create a Plunker.

Comment: `span*` was replaced by `col-*` in Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's pretty simple to use, don't worry you'll get it.

All you need to do is to create a row with 2 columns `(.col-sm-10)`, one as to fill in the left content of the image and the second is for the red box of yours `(.col-sm-2)`. ***The main motive here is to create a 12 column grid system.***

Then in the first columns make another row and add 2 Columns again, one for the `9/11 Conspiracy news` and the other for the `terrorists are plotting news`

And now comes your blue `<hr>` seperator and after that create another row and add 4 columns for `other stories section`

I've used the most popular `bootstrap version 3.3.1` to demonstrate your solution.

**Fiddle Demo** : [**http://jsfiddle.net/auy5y8e1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/auy5y8e1/)

*Resize the fiddle window to see if its working fine...*

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">
                     <h6 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>Here's Why 9/11 Conspiracy</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h9 class="span10">Newspaper</h9>
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                     <h6 class="text-center">Here's Why 9/11 Conspiracy</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="height:0.3em;" color='#000000' />                    
            <div class="row">                       
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <h4 class="text-center">Here's Why 9/11 Conspiracy Theories Still Thrive In America</h4>
                     <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Mr.Man</i></h5>
                    <hr>
                    <p style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><span class="firstcharacter">D</span>ublin, It was a sunny and clear Tuesday morning in Knoxville, Tennessee. Sitting in the kitchen of my girlfriend's apartment, I was eating a bowl of cereal -- Honey Nut Cheerios, I still remember -- and browsing the web before making the 15-minute drive to campus for class.</p>
                </div>                      
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>Terrorists are plotting to blow up five planes</h1>
                    <p><b>The threat has been taken so seriously it came close to leading to an outright ban on all hand luggage, a senior insider has revealed.</b></p>
                </div>                                              
            </div>                  
            <div class="row">
                <hr class="span10" style="height:0.3em;" color='#3090C7' />
            </div>                  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <h5 class="text-center" style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non</p>
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div>
                <h4 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'>Trending Stories</h4>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <h5 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
            <story>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit <b> amet risus.</b></story>                       <h5 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
            <story>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. <b> amet risus.</b></story>
            <h5 style='font-family: "DroidSerif",serif;'><i>Other Story</i></h5>
            <story>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.<b> amet risus.</b></story>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see now, so I should stick to .col instead of span.Thank you!

Comment: Yes, .col grids are simple and very easy to understand..
Good luck :)